# Dragging images in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I am using a listbox to bind a list of images using the code:

```
       <ListBox Name="lstBoxImages"  Height="645" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Height="Auto" Width="480" ItemHeight="120" ItemWidth="120"></toolkit:WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Width="120"  BorderThickness="2">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="110" >
                            <Image  Height="110" Width="110" Source="{Binding imageName}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Now i want to drag the images and shift the location of images. Can anyone help me out on this?
An example would be appreciable.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can find an sample project here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL4DragDropListBox.aspx?pageflow=Fluid&fid=1572066&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2009/12/silverlight-drag-and-drop-listboxitem.html

Comment: thank you for the link but what i want in for Windows Phone dragging within a single listbox.